# Fluorescent To LED Tube Swab - Only One Side Works

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, light, ballast

I have old 4ft fluorescent fixtures in the basement (about 10 years). They are [the NEW232120REBN](https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Fluorescent-Wraps/Lithonia-Lighting/NEW232120REBN/product.aspx?zpid=859284) from Lithonia. The T12s are dying out so I bought some Philips InstantFit 32W-equivalent T8 LED tubes.

The thing is that the new LEDs don't work as pairs, just one per light fixture. I was hoping to for a lot of light from these, it's a major bummer to get light only from one side.

Some thoughts:

- There is no visible ballast, but I don't know anything about ballasts. I think it's an electronic ballast, but that's all I can figure from my research.
- I have some dimmers nearby, from [Lutron](https://helpatmyhome.com/lutron-diva-led-dimmer-review/), but these lights aren't on dimmers
- The holders (tombstones) seem to be pretty worn, but they click in and out ok.
- In one or two of the fixtures I put in the LED next to a fluorescent and it lit but super dim, like 10% of the light it should have.

Any tips? I'm totally lost as what to do next. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm "no ballast"?  A ballast is a box typically 1" x 1.5" x 9" at the smallest.   However there are some very cheap fixtures which have a few little black boxes scattered around the fixture, which substitute for the ballast.  How do you feel about rewiring the fixture for "ballast bypass"?

Comment: OK, found the ballast. Sunpark SL15 electronic

Comment: How long did it take the last set of T12's to fail?  I'm particularly interested in the number of *starts*....

Comment: Most of the T12s are at least 5 years old. Not many starts though since they are in a basement.